# Unable to install Deepin Desktop on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, desktop-environments

I am trying to install the Deepin desktop environment on my Ubuntu 17.04 machine from https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde.
Now I am following the instruction by using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dde
```

But I always get

```
"Unable to locate package dde"
```

Comment: Did you noticed any error after apt update? (Using `apt` instead of `apt-get` is the preferred way for 16.04+)

Comment: I don't see the dde package in that PPA. Perhaps the maintainer removed it permanently or temporarily. You should contact the maintainer and ask why it's like that.

Comment: @MichaelBay no there seems to be no error. I think I will try to contact the maintainer of the PPA

Comment: wait, let me test...

Comment: ... and confirmed, same error... Probably they changed the meta-package' s name and didn't update the instructions. (There a `dde-api` package but I'm not sure that's the one).

Comment: @MichaelBay The author just replied telling me that DDE for zesty has been build and I should be able to install it. However, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I checked with the maintainer of the repository and there was indeed a problem. Now DDE can be installed correctly following the provided instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Deepin desktop is supported on ubuntu 17.04, and that you can install it. I would wait for the developers sort it out. In fact, when executing the commands on a brand new clean install I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dde : Depends: dde-control-center (> 2.90.5) but it is not going to be            installed
   Depends: dde-daemon but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: deepin-metacity but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: startdde but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: dde-session-ui but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: dde-trash-plguin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I get the same error. I have just contacted the maintainer of the repository about it.